# I want save all items in ListView to pdf file

Tags: java, android, listview, save, export

I wrote a barcode reader program that displays barcodes in a listview

No matter how hard I tried, I could not save my watch list items to a PDF file by pressing a button, please help me.

```
@SuppressWarnings("ALL")
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button scanBtn, btnok;

    TextView  messageFormat,ragham ;
    ArrayList<String> barcodelist = new ArrayList<>();

    HashSet<String> hashSet = new HashSet<String>();

    ArrayAdapter <String> adapter;
    String filename = "";
    String filepath = "";



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // referencing and initializing
        // the button and textviews
        scanBtn = findViewById(R.id.btnscann);
        filename = "barcodes.txt";
        ListView list1 = findViewById(R.id.list1);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,barcodelist);

        list1.setAdapter(adapter);



        scanBtn.setOnClickListener(this);



        Button b=findViewById(R.id.btnok);
        btnok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                ObjectOutputStream out;
               Object[] objs = new Object[list1.getCount()];
               for (int i = 0 ; i < list1.getCount();i++) {
                  Object obj = (Object)list1.getItemAtPosition(i);
                  objs[i] = obj;
               }                try {
                   out = new ObjectOutputStream
                           (new FileOutputStream(new File(filename)));
                   out.writeObject(objs);
                   out.flush();
                    out.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
               }


            }
});
```

Comment: First of all, you are writing to a `txt` file, but your question is about PDF?  Also your list is displaying strings, why don't you simply write strings to the file, why are you casting list items to `Object` first?

Comment: Also you are opening and closing the file for every item in the list, you should probably open the file *before* the loop and close it *after* the loop.

Comment: I am a newbie
I want to save the items that are displayed in the list view with a button in PDF format so that I can use them later. Please, if possible, solve this problem.

Comment: Reading the docs about the built-in PdfDocument API would be a good place to start: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument

Comment: Also try this tutorial, I haven't followed it myself but it looks very simple. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-generate-a-pdf-file-in-android-app/

Comment: As I said before, I just left and now I'm really confused. If you can write me the code so I can understand more, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really should not use a list view now a days, a recyclerview is more efficient for display to a screen but as you can draw view direct to a PDF with [PDFDocument](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument) a list view or recyclerview can either create non standard PDF pages sizes to fit everything in one page or you have to work out how to split the items over multiple pages.

I've done a [full example](https://github.com/Zardozz/RecyclerviewPdf) of how to draw a recyclerview to multiple page pdf.